# calculator for BMI, need help fixing the clear button

Tags: java

i posted a previous question about how to implement actionlisteners.
ive completed the class, and probably could of been done better with arrays i think.
but this way worked for me.
the problem is. when i click the clear button it doesnt clear it because my number buttons have the update variable on it which when press stores the number in it. if that makes sense.

is there a way where i can work around it?

```js
// import packages
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;


// class
public class Lab31Panel extends JPanel {

 // data declarations

 private JRadioButton k2pButton;
 private JRadioButton p2kButton;
 private ButtonGroup weight;
 private JPanel selectConversion;
 private JButton jb0, jb1, jb2, jb3, jb4, jb5, jb6, jb7, jb8, jb9, jbminus, jbclear, jbconvert;
 private JTextArea display;
 private String update = "";


 //constructor to initiate data and set up GUI
 public Lab31Panel() {
  setLayout(new BorderLayout());

  // organizing radio buttons and their behaviours
  k2pButton = new JRadioButton("Kilograms to Pounds");
  p2kButton = new JRadioButton("Pounds to Kilograms");
  weight = new ButtonGroup();
  weight.add(k2pButton);
  weight.add(p2kButton);


  // adding components to panel to be south of the GUI
  selectConversion = new JPanel();
  selectConversion.add(k2pButton);
  selectConversion.add(p2kButton);


  add(selectConversion, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

  //setting up west area of GUI
  JPanel westPanel = new JPanel();
  JPanel convert = new JPanel();

  // setting up components for the  west of the GUI
  westPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 3));
  westPanel.add(jb0 = new JButton("0"));
  westPanel.add(jb1 = new JButton("1"));
  westPanel.add(jb2 = new JButton("2"));
  westPanel.add(jb3 = new JButton("3"));
  westPanel.add(jb4 = new JButton("4"));
  westPanel.add(jb5 = new JButton("5"));
  westPanel.add(jb6 = new JButton("6"));
  westPanel.add(jb7 = new JButton("7"));
  westPanel.add(jb8 = new JButton("8"));
  westPanel.add(jb9 = new JButton("9"));
  westPanel.add(jbminus = new JButton("-"));
  westPanel.add(jbclear = new JButton("clear"));
  westPanel.add(jbconvert = new JButton("convert"));



  add(westPanel, BorderLayout.WEST);

  //setting up east components
  JPanel eastPanel = new JPanel();
  eastPanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
  display = new JTextArea();
  display.setEditable(false);

  eastPanel.add(display, BorderLayout.CENTER);
  add(eastPanel);


  jb0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb0) update += 0;
    display.setText(update);

   }
  });

  jb1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb1) update += 1;
    display.setText(update);
   }
  });



  jb2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb2) update += 2;
    display.setText(update);


   }
  });

  jb3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb3) update += 3;
    display.setText(update);

   }
  });

  jb4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb4) update += 4;
    display.setText(update);

   }
  });

  jb5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb5) update += 5;
    display.setText(update);

   }
  });

  jb6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb6) update += 6;
    display.setText(update);

   }
  });

  jb7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb7) update += 7;
    display.setText(update);

   }
  });

  jb8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb8) update += 8;
    display.setText(update);

   }
  });

  jb9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jb9) update += 9;
    display.setText(update);

   }
  });



  jbclear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object source = e.getSource();
    if (source == jbclear) display.setText(null);

   }
  });

  jbconvert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Object source = e.getSource();

    double convert = Double.parseDouble(update);
    double totalp2k = convert / 2.24;
    double totalk2p = convert * 2.24;


    if (p2kButton.isSelected() == true) {
     if (source == jbconvert) {

      display.setText(update + " : " + totalp2k);
     }

    } else if (k2pButton.isSelected() == true) {

     display.setText(update + " : " + totalk2p);
    }

   }
  });




 } //end constructor


} // end class
```

```js
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Lab31Frame
{
    
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        JFrame myFrame = new JFrame( "Lab 3: Question 2" );
        
        // create an instance of Panel and add to frame
        Lab31Panel myPanel = new Lab31Panel();
        myFrame.add( myPanel );
        
        // set up functionality of frame
        myFrame.setSize( 500, 310 );
        myFrame.setVisible( true );
        myFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
        
    }//end main
} // end class
```

Comment: Try to cut this down to a [mcve].  And remove the code snippets; they're only for html/css/js.

Answer (score 1):

In the ActionListener for jbclear, you also need to clear update:

```
jbclear.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        Object source = e.getSource();
        if (source == jbclear) {
            display.setText(null);
            update = "";
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: oh wow it was that simple lmao. thank you